# For AWS Cognito Built-In login, where does "legal text" appear?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

According to the AWS Cognito [Customizing the Built-in Sign-in and Sign-up Webpage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html)s you can customize a field named "Legal Text". I'd like to display some legal text but I don't see how I can set the actual text or where it appears. Any idea?

Comment: Did you end up finding the solution to this?

Comment: Any news about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Legal Text" in the Cognito Hosted UI customization options is somewhat ambiguously named. The text actually refers to the disclaimer under your Federated Identities when signing in,

> We won't post to any of your accounts without asking first.

[image: Cognito Hosted UI Legal Text]

This text obviously doesn't appear if you are not using federated identities such as Facebook or Google. Currently, there is no option to add any custom legal text such as a copyright or privacy policy notice

Comment: I see. I was hoping we we could add some legal text using the simple built in dialog that just allows entering Email/Password or clicking Sign Up. This way we could should users legal text before they sign up.